# Baking Roughness and Normal on Multiple UV is successful, but when I link image texture is partially inactive

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders, texture-baking, baking

I have 2 shader node and 2 UV Map on the same object.
Shader Node A :  UV Map A/
Shader Node B  : UV Map B.
After I bake a new texture this object  to Multiple UV between A and B (Multiple UV Name: UV Map C)

And I got an Image with diffuse roughness and normal  in all parts in Multiple UV Name: UV Map C.

But when I link the image texture to the object and turn on reading at multiple UV Name: UV Map C., Roughness and Normal doesn't work in the part of UV map A but UV map B no problem,
but Diffuse has no problem Both UV Map A and UV Map B.

Why is it? and how can I fix this problem?

This picture is shader node C and turn on UV Map C  and I use blender3.0

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you need to tell Blender which UV map you want it to use for the lookups on your new texture.  Use a UV Map node to specify, then plug its output into your image texture's vector input.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but I have tried linking UV Map node with Image texture 's vector but nothing happens. The result is still the same error.